# GPO for scheduled tasks not applying to certain servers, no errors in logs

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

I have two servers out in an OU that are not taking scheduled tasks as specified in the GPO. The same GPO applies correctly to other machines in the same OU with the same permissions, so I don't believe it to be a permissions or routing issue.

The only error I can find is when I pull a report query of the applied settings, under the "Scheduled Tasks" category - it says "An unknown error occurred while data was gathered for this extension. Details: Invalid class." Anyone seen this before or know how to further investigate?

AD server pushing the policy is 2008 R2, client servers are 2008 R2 (but policy is applying correctly to 2012 R2 machines).

EDIT for future readers: misbehaving boxes were NOT R2 machines, hence the problem.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can happen if you edited the GPO with RSAT on a machine like an Windows 8/8.1/10 or on a server running 2012R2, even if it's a 2008R2's AD.

As for planned task if it's on a 2012R2 you edited the GPO, then it push 2012R2's option that will be unknown to a 2008R2 to be applied.

Try to create a new GPO to deploy to your 2008R2 to rule that out.

Sorry for the french printscreen, but there the display on a 2008R2, and the setting you should select to have it work on an 2008.

[image]

For reference, there is a printscreen to edit the same GPO but from a 2008 non R2 directly:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure a completely follow. The GPO was created on a S2008R2 box, which applied on itself and all 2012 boxes correctly. It won't push to 2 of 3 2008 machines. 

If I understand correctly, I should create a separate GPO for 2008 boxes, and not apply it to 2012 machines? I'm not sure I understand all the details or reasoning, but I'm happy to try it.

Comment: @customcables067 Yes, but if it's a simple task you can create the task to target 2008 +, and it will work on all server. I'am adding a printscreen to the answer. The windows show **vista**, but it's the same core as 2008 non R2. If you select a normal task, it include option that didnt existed in 2008 non R2

Comment: Yeah, it's already using that. :/

Comment: @customcables067 ok, then to be sure you could add the group policy management to a 2008 server and create the gpo from there directly. check the other printscreen I will add, as it show how it look like on a 2008, same AD, but the option is not the same as the RSAT run on a 2008.

Comment: Well, now I feel like a moron... those two misbehaving boxes were NOT R2 as I previously assumed. Didn't think I still had any non-R2 boxes.... *SIGH*. Thanks...! (to be clear, I had to select the "normal" version for this to work on a non-r2 box.)